# nodemailer attachment create excel file error in nestjs

Tags: excel, nestjs, typeorm, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email after creating an excel file.

I use nestjs and typeorm, my code is below.

```js
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

let file: Map<string, any> = new Map();
      for (const t in UserType) {
        const data = await this.myDataRepository.find({
          select: ['userId', 'userName'],
          where: {userType : t},
          order: {
            userId: 'DESC',
          },
        });
        //createExcelFile
        var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet<UserGameCount>(data);
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'TestWB.xlsx');

        var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
          type: 'base64',
          bookType: 'xlsx',
          bookSST: false,
        });

        file.set(t, wbout);
      }

      const result = await this.commonService.testsendMail(
        'myEmail@gmail',
        file,
      );
```

```js
async testsendMail(email: string, file: Map<string, any>) {
    try {
      const att: {
        filename: string;
        contents: any;
        contentTransferEncoding: string;
        contentType: string;
      }[] = [];
      file.forEach((value: any, key: string) => {
        att.push({
          filename: key + '.xlsx',
          contents: Buffer.from(value).toString('base64'),
          contentTransferEncoding: 'base64',
          contentType:
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        });
      });
      const mailOptions = {
        from: 'your mail',
        to: email,
        subject: 'subject',
        html: 'content',
        attachments: att,
      };

      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      
    }
  }
```

Emails are sent normally.
Attachments are also sent normally according to the number of userTypes.

But the size of the file is `0kb` and the file does not open.

Even if I change the data to json format, Even if I change the XLSX.write option to buffer instead of base64, the same error occurs.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the part of generating excel using `excel4node` instead of `xlsx`.

```js
var wb = new XLSX.Workbook();
var ws = wb.addWorksheet(t);

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          ws.cell(i + 1, 1).number(data[i].userId);
          ws.cell(i + 1, 2).string(data[i].name);
        }

const filename: string = new Date().getMonth() + '.xlsx';
      const f = await wb.writeToBuffer();
```